# Cascading databound comboboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm new here this is my first question and I beforehand apologize for any lack of information, search or tags in the post or anything at all.

I'm writing a pretty simple winforms program, and I'm having problems with cascading combo boxes, pretty much like country>Estate>City I'm new to this, I'm using Entity Framework and I'm getting by with something like this:

```
private void Form_CadAnimal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DbClinvetEntities ctx = new DbClinvetEntities())
    {
        cmb_especie.DataSource = ctx.Especie;
        cmb_especie.DisplayMember = "Nome";
        cmb_especie.ValueMember = "EspecieID"
        cmb_raca.DataSource = ctx.raca;
        cmb_raca.DisplayMember = "Nome";
        cmb_raca.ValueMember = "RacaID";
    }
}
```

So far so good all is going ok, I get them to be populated, I've found countless posts on the matter, but perhaps for lack of knowledge I could not relate them to my situation.
now all I would like to do is filter cmb_Raca by the value selected in cmb_Especie, just to make it clearer Raca table has a foreign key on Especie table, pretty much like you would expect country>estate to be.

I've found posts where a new context is generated on SelectedIndexChanged and a whole new binding is done, but I wonder if there is a way to make this work without making further calls to the Db, any way to take the list of objects and work them offline after the first access?

Sorry if this is anyhow unclear, I'll glady edit the post to provide further information if necessary.

Comment: Winforms is pretty much the least automatic UI library you'll find...you're going to have to attach to an event and update the DataSource of the dependent tables each time.

Comment: sry for the question but how do I update the DataSource? I've tried to make things like DataView dv = combobox.DataSource as DataView but it always returns null, tried with some other types as well with no success.

Comment: In your code you're already updating the DataSource: `cmb_especie.DataSource = ctx.Especie`...I could be wrong here, thus the comment rather than an answer, but that should do the trick.

Comment: You could also bind to a list and Clear and Refill the list whenever the other SelectedItem changes.

Comment: oh now I get what you meant, I would have to manually keep track of items and update the datasource as things go happening, is that it? so I should keep some short of List<SomeObject> and add/remove by the selectedIndex, I just hoped there was a quick way to do this, beign it what it seems to me a pretty every-day task

Comment: Yup, that's correct.  Win Forms is *not* a quick way to do anything more complex than displaying and inputting data.

Comment: It's pretty sparse as far as interfaces go.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things out, I guess I'll have to make it manually then, since I know little of winforms, but nothing of wpf haha, have a good week

Answer (score 0):

try using the SelectedIndex as your query select command.you can build a module for talking to the database that takes the SelectedIndex.ToString() as a parameter to build your Query and fill data to your form based on that. the Combobox doesn't necessarily have to be databound when it is used that way.

Comment: then I would be making a new call do Db each time the Index is changed, or at least I believe,I want to avoid this behavior. Thanks for the reply anyhow

Comment: Are you planning on using a datagridview control or filling this all in ComboBoxes?

Comment: Sorry as I said I'm pretty new to visual studio, c# and all of this, I'm not sure how I could solve this with a datagridview, I was expecting to do this with a couple of textboxes and comboboxes, but I'm open to suggestions

Comment: the DataGridView Control can be loaded once when you load the control and you can set its sort to order however you want but it will fill with all the data from your dataset. otherwise, you are going to have to ask for the information every time you select the index unless you want to take a long time loading the information in the beginning as it is populating many lists and that doesn't seem too practical.